# How can I read and write to a text file on a dropbox link

Tags: delphi, text-files, dropbox

I am trying to assign a text file to a dropbox link so that I can read and write to it from anywhere instead of using a local text file. I have tried the following code, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
assignfile(txtfile, 'http:/dropbox.com/s/0872ng3r7rg0pwq/share.txt?raw=1');
rewrite(txtfile);
writeln(txtfile, 'text');
closefile(txt)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You cannot access a drop box link as though it is a file. Use one of the drop box APIs. Mixing ancient legacy Pascal I/O that should have been put to one side 15 years ago, with modern cloud based storage, is something of a juxtaposition.

Comment: If you have a dropbox folder on your computer, it will automatcally be shared with Dropbox. This way I can easily share a shopping list in Windows, OS X with an iOS app that uses Dropbox. If I add an item to the list on my Mac, and save it, my wife will see the added item a few seconds later on her iPhone.

Comment: You are not going to make your chat program this way. Why not listen to us I stead of ignoring our advice. We keep telling you that you can't make chat this way. You are a beginner and we have years of experience. You are simply wasting your time.

Comment: It's a project I have due for about a month from now, I'm sure learning how to use the Dropbox API will take some time. Reading / writing to the file through Dropbox isn't required - I can use it in a shared folder on the network. I have roughly read some of the documentation Martin linked although it doesn't make much sense to me and I wouldn't know where to start.

Comment: You've got no chance of making a good chat program this way. I can only hope that this is for homework at school. If it's commercial then you're in big trouble.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot easily work with a remote file like this. Unless Dropbox supports a protocol like Samba, which would enable you to mount it as a virtual drive, you need to do some more work with the file.

The course of action here would be:

1. Download the contents of the file.
2. Edit it however you want.
3. Upload it back to the server. To do that, you need to use Dropbox API. See https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-upload for example (I am not sure if this particular method is what you need, I am guessing).

Comment: Is there a simpler alternative to using a dropbox link that allows public to read / write?

Comment: @Balliztica Start by reading the API documentation as Martin linked in his answer. You'll find everything you need to know there.

Comment: You might find FTP simpler than Dropbox if you're not familiar with Web APIs and aren't keen to learn. However, the steps listed above will remain the same for any service: Download, edit, and upload. If you want your program to literally *edit* a *remote file*, then the APIs involved will be *much* more complicated — imagine implementing Google Docs. That's not the direction to go, if you're already afraid of using Dropbox's relatively simple API.

Comment: To use Dropbox, you don't need to use the API. A Dropbox folder will automatically upload a (modified) file once it is saved. Works on my Mac as well as on Windows. Never tried Linux, but it would not surprise me if it worked there too. All Dropbox folders, on any supported OS, with the same settings will be updated a few seconds later.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis For clarification, are application able to read and write files to the local Dropbox folder?  Or have Dropbox somehow limited access?  Secondly, will local Dropbox files be updated when they are updated on the Dropbox server by another person?  I'm pretty sure I know the answers - this is the approach I'd take.  Why not submit it as an answer?

Comment: @MichaelVincent: It is a folder like any other folder in the filesystem. It is just guarded by some software that syncs all Dropox folders (of the same user) with each other. Before Github, I used it to sync my software on all computers, simply by saving files. You just had to put your directory in the Dropbox folder.

Comment: Is it possible for me to have a dropbox folder inside a shared folder on my network so that others can access / write to it?

Comment: @Rudy That forces the user to install Dropbox client software. Which is a new requirement.

Comment: @David: Indeed. If it is installed, it is very easy though. Doesn't the Dropbox API require an installation too?

Comment: @Rudy No, why would it? And "it is very easy", well yes, but who says that users will want to install such a heavyweight just to run a chat program.

Comment: Dropbox is not a heavyweight. I have it on all my computers.